# after something is done

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I just need to check with you. Is this sentence correct as it does not sound familiar to me.

After the scan is done, we analyse the results.

What I want to say is after some task "scan" is finished, we do the analysis. The analysis can not be done before the scan is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is fine. When describing a process involving stages or steps, we can use the present tense: After the salt is dissolved, the flour is added; after the cutting is done, we pack the pieces in bags; after the scan is done (or has been completed) we analyse the results.